# Iterating through drawables

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an Android app that will display a list of students.

I've created a class called `Classmates` to define each student:

```
public class Classmates {
    String name;
    int classNum;
    int drawableId;

    public Classmates(String name, int classNum, int drawableId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.classNum = classNum;
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
}
```

For each student I have a photo with a numbered filename (`R.drawable.num1`, `R.drawable.num2`, ...). However, when I try and initialize each student:

```
private void initializeData() {
    classmates = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 38; i++)
    {
        // Exclude student 32
        if(!(i==32)) classmates.add(new Classmates(classmateName[i],R.drawable.num(i)); // error
    }
}
```

It doesn't work and gives me an error. How do I iterate through all the drawables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `getIdentifier()`?

```
private void initializeData() {
    classmates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 38; i++) {
        //Exclude number 32
        if (!(i == 32)) {
            Context ctx = getContext();
            int resId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(String.format("num%d", i), "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());
            classmates.add(new Classmates(classmateName[i], resId);
        }
    }
}
```